# Votes on posts are not persisted

Tags: support, voting, upvotes

I am a new SO user. I recently got the privilege to upvote. I was reading posts that I believe will help me in my endeavors so I opted to vote them up. I've just noticed that my votes were not saved.

**For example** 
When I upvote and leave/refresh and revisit the post, my vote isn't saved. And on my profile the votes cast number stays the same.

Is there a moderation phase before votes are applied? Or is it me or my account that cannot vote?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question a bit? Do you mean they're automatically being ***reverted***? Automatically cast wouldn't make sense - you need to vote yourself.

Comment: You can vote up from 15 rep: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up. It's not automatic; you need to click the arrow then it turns orange.

Comment: Yes, it turns orange sir @jonrsharpe, but the total number of votes that I cast stays the same.

Comment: That doesn't sound right, there's no moderation period for votes.

Comment: @Rob sir not being reverted. It just look that my votes does not cast at the very moment. The arrows turns to orange but when i check into my profile, the number of votes cast remains the same. Also, in the badge tracker, the **suffrage** and **vox populi** did not increase its numbers.

Comment: sir @jonrsharpe, yes exactly sir. These past days when i reach 20 rep. I can easily vote and that vote is implemented right away. I got 11 votes all upvotes. But recently its not changing.

Comment: @Rob sir I'm not voting on my own questions and answers, I'm voting for the question and answers that I have read from other users.

Comment: @Freak I didn't mean that you were voting for your own posts - I meant that you need to cast votes yourself, there's nothing automatic involved. The phrasing was unclear, so I was trying to clarify. The issue you're having is that either votes are not being accepted, or they're being immediately reverted.

Comment: @Rob sorry sir I miss understood. Pardon me. :)

Comment: mhh my guess is the browser issue with javascript, do you happen to be using windows 98 on a pentium 1 machine? try switching browsers

Comment: @konzo I'm using Win 8 on a intel core i3 on an internet speed of 10mbps max

Comment: @Freak..  My sincere apologies, what happens when you upvote is that the browser displays a fake result of your action then issues an xhr request to SO in the background... use developer console to see what is happening to that request

Comment: @konzo sir, no problem :) . I tried inspecting in the console but there is no logged error. This time, the numbers in the **badges** are increasing but in the **votes cast** it still remains the same. I'm having a conclusion that this is caused by my browsers cache or my DNS.

Comment: @Sayse i think so sir, it seems its reading cache from the past not at the moment. Do you have the idea how to fixed this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When i check into my profile, the number of votes cast remains the same. Also, in the badge tracker, the suffrage and vox populi did not increase its numbers.

These numbers aren't updated straight away, they are cached values. If you check back tomorrow you should find that the number of votes has increased, and you are closer to gaining the badge.

Comment: Great! Now this comforts me. I'll check it back often these coming hours. I also have noticed that from 11 votes at the time i ask these question, now it's 16, so therefore, it takes effect after a few minutes or hours perhaps.

Comment: @Freak - Just make sure you are voting based on the quality of the post(s), not whether or not they may help you.

Comment: yes sir, I'm keeping that in mind. I'm learning the ethics of this site. Plus, I'm voting those answer that did help me in my problems and those questions that I myself are overcoming.